# XML-RPC: Add category to post data

Tags: xml-rpc

I have a service that puts a daily post to my blog via XML-RPC.  It doesn't offer me any control of what category it goes into so I want to just add a filter/hook to add the category I want into the incoming post data:

```
add_action ('xmlrpc_call', 'check_xmlrpc_call' );

function check_xmlrpc_call( $method )
{
    if( 'wp.newPost' === $method )
    {
        add_filter( 'xmlrpc_wp_insert_post_data', 'add_xmlrpc_category_post_data' );
    }
}

function add_xmlrpc_category_post_data( $post_data )
{
    //not sure how to add category to the post data :(

    return $post_data;  
}
```

I think something like this in my `functions.php` would work?  I just am not sure the correct format to add a category to the post data?

Maybe this?

```
$post_data['terms'] = array('category' => array(207))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Assigning posts to taxonomy terms in XML-RPC:

Let's assume your setup is:

```
                                     xml-rpc
                                    wp.newPost
                  (sender) site A -------------> site B (receiver)
```

and you want to assign the new posts to a given taxonomy terms on site **B**.

### From site B:

Then you can try the following, on the *receiving* site **B**:

```
$post_data['tax_input'] = array( 'category' => array( 207 ) );
```

where the `category` taxonomy with id `207` already exists on the site `B`.

It's also possible to use the other supported parameters of `wp_insert_post()`, like `post_category` or `tags_input`. In your case you could therefore also use:

```
$post_data['post_category'] = array( 207 );
```

### From site A:

Notice that the `terms` and `terms_names` parameters are supported by the payload of the `wp.newPost` query, from the `sending` site **A**.

Here's an example for the site **A**, how one could add terms of a given taxonomy:

```
$result = $client->query( 
    'wp.newPost', 
    array(
        $blog_id,
        $user,
        $password,
        array(
            'post_status'  => 'draft',
            'post_title'   => 'Test',
            'post_content' => 'We are testing XML-RPC!',
            'terms_names'  => array( 
                'post_tag' => array( 'xml-rpc' ), 
                'category' => array( 'wordpress-testing' ),
            ),
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot.  Just curious - how is tax_input different from post_category?  I'm not using a custom post type or anything so couldnt I also use:  $post_data['post_category'] = array(207)

Comment: Yes that should also work, since `post_category` is supported by `wp_insert_post()`.

Comment: Did that work for you?

Comment: No unfortunately not. I'm not sure how to even debug it to see what could be going wrong.

Comment: These methods worked fine when I tested them. You must make sure that the corresponding category exists. So you can create a post but not assign the category to it?