# New post created with XML-RPC works fine but fails to assign category

Tags: xml-rpc

I am creating WordPress post from my desktop using xmlrpc. Everything else (e.g. title, description, custom_fields) except category is working fine. The category is not assigning to the post.

So far I have tried all this lines -

```
$content['terms'] = array('post_category' => array( 10 ) ); //Not working
$content['terms'] = array('category' => array( 10 ) ); //Not working
$content['terms'] = array('post_category' => 10 ); //Not working
$content['post_category'] = array('terms' => array( 10 ) ); //Not working
$content['terms'] = array(10); //Not working

$content['categories'] = array(10); //This used to work in olden days but not now
```

Note: 10 is the category ID which do exist in my website. I have also tried writing the id inside single/double quote marks ie. "10" and '10'

Comment: If this used to work and no longer does, it sounds like a bug in WordPress core. Have you reported it on [trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/)?

Comment: Did you try these suggestions [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/171961/26350)?

Comment: @birgire Yes tried. The lines I have mentioned above contains the same.

Comment: @NathanJohnson I think wordpress have added new rules from Ver3.4. As per wp documentation, it says (added in 3.4) _struct terms: Taxonomy names as keys, array of term IDs as values._ https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Posts#wp.newPost

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. Actually it is my mistake.
I am using XML-RPC **metaWeblog.newPost** but I was applying solution which is for XML-RPC **wp.newPost**

So correct solution in case of **xml-rpc metaWeblog.newPost** is -

```
$content['categories'] = array('Featured'); //Works.
```

And in case of **xml-rpc wp.newPost**, it is -

```
$content['terms'] = array('category' => array( 10 ) ); //Works
```

Hope this will help who is newbie like me.